# Docker pull: operation not permitted

Tags: docker

I'm getting this error when pulling some docker images (but not all):

```
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): operation not permitted
```

For example: `docker pull nginx` works, but not `docker pull redis`.

I get the same result wether i run the command with a user that is part of the `docker` group, using sudo or as root.

If i run dockerd in debug mode i see this in the logs:

```
DEBU[0025] Downloaded 5233d9aed181 to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob023191751 
DEBU[0025] Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e5290b8c50d601918458c912d937a4f6d4801ecaa90afb3b729a5dc0fc405afc/diff 
DEBU[0027] Applied tar sha256:16ada34affd41b053ca08a51a3ca92a1a63379c1b04e5bbe59ef27c9af98e5c6 to e5290b8c50d601918458c912d937a4f6d4801ecaa90afb3b729a5dc0fc405afc, size: 79185732 
(...)
DEBU[0029] Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c5c0cfb9907a591dc57b1b7ba0e99ae48d0d7309d96d80861d499504af94b21d/diff 
DEBU[0029] Cleaning up layer c5c0cfb9907a591dc57b1b7ba0e99ae48d0d7309d96d80861d499504af94b21d: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): operation not permitted 
INFO[0029] Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): operation not permitted 
INFO[0029] Layer sha256:938f1cd4eae26ed4fc51c37fa2f7b358418b6bd59c906119e0816ff74a934052 cleaned up 
(...)
```

If i run `watch -n 0 "sudo ls -lt /var/lib/docker/overlay2/"` while the image is pulling, i can see new folders appearing (and disappearing after it fails) and the permissions on `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/` are `root:root:700` so i don't think it's exactly a permission issue.

Here are some detail about the environment:

I have a proxmox running the LXC container where i'm having the issue.
The container itself is running Debian 8.
And here are the various versions:

```
$> uname -a
Linux [redacted-hostname] 4.10.15-1-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.10.15-15 (Fri, 23 Jun 2017 08:57:55 +0200) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:20:04 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:18:59 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

$>docker info
Containers: 20
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 20
Images: 28
Server Version: 17.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: cfb82a876ecc11b5ca0977d1733adbe58599088a
runc version: 2d41c047c83e09a6d61d464906feb2a2f3c52aa4
init version: 949e6fa
Kernel Version: 4.10.15-1-pve
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.906GiB
Name: resumed-dev
ID: EBJ6:AFVS:L3RC:ZEE7:A6ZJ:WDQE:GTIZ:RXHA:P4AQ:QJD7:H6GG:YIQB
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 16
 Goroutines: 24
 System Time: 2017-08-17T14:17:07.800849127+02:00
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

Comment: Are you running docker as sudo?

Comment: @PhilippClaßen Yes, the exact command i run is `sudo dockerd -D`

Comment: @iCart as which user are you using docker? (as which user are you executing docker pull... ) Is this user inside the docker group?

Comment: @PhilippClaßen Yes, i am in the group. Also, it turns out i can pull some images but not others (see edited question). I'll admit i'm very confused now

Comment: Can you give more details about your environment? E.g. output of `docker version`, `docker info`, operating system (`uname -a`), etc.

Comment: And, yeah, the most basic question: does your disc or partition have enough space?

Comment: This can happen for huge number of images. `docker images` and then try to clean up the previous container images `docker rmi -f [container id]`

Comment: @gesellix i added the requested info in the question

Comment: @Ultraviolet, i tried that, but i get the same result. (it also happens on images i don't already have)

Comment: Stop the docker service, do a `rm -rf /var/lib/docker` and then start it again and pull a `redis` and `nginx` images and see if the issue still persists

Comment: I don't see any `Security Options:` entry in the output of `docker info`. Not sure if it should always appear, though. Is that a special/non-official Docker build?

Comment: @TarunLalwani The issue still persists after doing a `mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker_backup`. ´docker pull nginx´ works, but not for redis

Comment: I would suggest open a issue with docker then

Comment: @gesellix I double checked, i don't see any `Security Options:` either, i did miss two warnings, though, i added them in the question.
Afaik it's the offical Docker build, the exact entry from `/etc/apt/sources.list` is `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jessie stable`

Comment: I don't know anything about proxmox, which is why I assume the issue comes from some kind of issue between proxmox and Docker. Like @TarunLalwani suggested, you should file an issue with Docker or Moby. AFAIK the warnings about iptables aren't be relevant for your issue.

Comment: @iCart: do you have any solution yet? I encounter the same problem but with a somewhat different setup: docker 17.09.0-ce on xenial on lxd 1.28 on xenial on vmware on windows7 (high stack, i know). My lxd container is privileged, no traces of an apparmor problem, docker daemon debug output same. fails here on these images: redis, mysql, postgres, cassandra, tutum/hello-world and succeeds on hello-world, nginx, tomcat:alpine

Comment: @RemigiusStalder Not really, i ended up creating another container and redeploying everything on it and the problem disapeared.

Comment: @iCart thanks for the answer - meanwhile (a couple of hours ago) I have resolved the problem: I have set security.privileged = true in the lxd config (I was wrongly assuming this was the case in my terraform script - but I have set the wrong privileged option). I don't know about privileged containers in lxc, but it seems that docker (still) needs them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: This will be fixed by any release after December 18, 2017 of Moby via [this merge](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/35794#event-1390655486). Will update again when fully incorporated into Docker.

If your container is unprivileged, this appears to be an issue with the `overlay2` storage driver for Docker. This does not appear to be an issue with `overlay` ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35245)). So either [utilize the `overlay` storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-overlay-or-overlay2-storage-driver) instead of `overlay2`, or make your container privileged.

Answer (score 4):

I have almost the same environment as you, and met the same problem.
Some image works perfectly (alpine), while some images fails at cleaning up (ubuntu).

`strace -f dockerd -D` then `docker pull` or `docker load` gives the reason:

```
mknodat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/agpgart", S_IFCHR|0660, makedev(10, 175)) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Unprivileged container prohibit mknod by design. If you insist nesting Docker inside lxc, you will have to choose privileged container. (And notice that existing unprivileged container cannot be converted to privileged container directly due to uid/gid mapping)

Comment: this also applies to docker inside lxd (docker 17.09.0-ce).