# Gunicorn not able to connect to sock file on Alpine

Tags: python, gunicorn

There are a lot of questions asked on this topic but none have helped me.

I am trying to connect Gunicorn to `/tmp/gunicorn.sock` but I keep on getting `operation not permitted`. My `gunicorn.conf.py` looks like:

```
import multiprocessing

# bind = '127.0.0.1:5000'
bind = 'unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock'

backlog = 2048
preload_app = True
max_requests = 2048
max_requests_jitter = 128

workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
worker_connections = 1000
timeout = 60
keepalive = 2

errorlog = '-'
loglevel = 'debug'
accesslog = '-'
access_log_format = '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'


def when_ready(server):
    open('/tmp/app-initialized', 'w').close()
```

and my logs are:

```
[2018-08-03 02:34:40 +0000] [116] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-08-03 02:34:40 +0000] [116] [DEBUG] connection to /tmp/gunicorn.sock failed: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
[2018-08-03 02:34:40 +0000] [116] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-08-03 02:34:41 +0000] [116] [DEBUG] connection to /tmp/gunicorn.sock failed: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
[2018-08-03 02:34:41 +0000] [116] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-08-03 02:34:42 +0000] [116] [DEBUG] connection to /tmp/gunicorn.sock failed: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
[2018-08-03 02:34:42 +0000] [116] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-08-03 02:34:43 +0000] [116] [DEBUG] connection to /tmp/gunicorn.sock failed: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
[2018-08-03 02:34:43 +0000] [116] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-08-03 02:34:44 +0000] [116] [DEBUG] connection to /tmp/gunicorn.sock failed: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
[2018-08-03 02:34:44 +0000] [116] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-08-03 02:34:45 +0000] [116] [ERROR] Can't connect to /tmp/gunicorn.sock
```

This looks like a permission error for the user, but that shouldn't be a problem because `gunicorn` is running as `root`

```
/opt/app # ps aux | grep gunicorn
  123 root      0:00 grep gunicorn
```

I have also tried creating a user and a group as `addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup` and changed the permission for `/tmp/` folder by doing `chown appuser:appgroup /tmp/` (because `gunicorn.sock` file was not created).

The contents in the OS are executing as `root` and I still get this error. How should I make it possible to run it via `gunicorn.sock` file?

**Update**

```
My `Dockerfile`:

FROM python:3.6.6-alpine3.8

# Update, install the required packages and clean downloaded package
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add postgresql-dev nginx supervisor && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Copy files
...

# setup all the configfiles
COPY config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY config/nginx-app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
COPY config/supervisor-app.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/

# Install requirements
...

EXPOSE 8113

CMD ["supervisord", "-n", "-c", "/opt/app/config/supervisor-app.conf"]
```

Comment: I guess you're using Docker. This may well be a Docker-specific problem. Can you share tte `Dockerfile` (ideally pared down to a [mcve], perhaps without `gunicorn` or even Python)?

Comment: Vaguely, this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731683/docker-pull-operation-not-permitted

Comment: @tripleee Updated it, Also I was trying to run this inside the docker itself as `docker --it ... sh`

Comment: @tripleee docker seems to be working fine actually.

Comment: The linked question says "mknod not permitted" which sounds like exactly your problem, but there are multiple weird things like this which are specific to Docker. If you can reduce this to a `Dockerfile` where `mknod` fails, at least you know where to look; but that sounds like basically a totally different question than this.

Comment: @tripleee I'm running the lates version of Docker and ya that could be a differnt question.

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/701384/loopback-device-in-a-linux-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the people at https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1849.

For creating sockets on the fly, you might have to put them in `/run/` i.e. `bind='unix:/run/gunicron.sock'` then you can use Nginx as a reverse proxy and serve through the given sock file.

**But why `/run/`?**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

> Run-time variable data: Information about the running system since
>   last boot, e.g., currently logged-in users and running daemons. Files
>   under this directory must be either removed or truncated at the
>   beginning of the boot process; but this is not necessary on systems
>   that provide this directory as a temporary filesystem (tmpfs).

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13972/what-is-this-new-run-filesystem for more information.